# ng-file-upload validation using file.$error

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to implement validation messages based on the file.$error. In my case I have the following html:

```
<input type="file" ng-model="personalImageFile" ngf-select="" ngf-accept="'.jpg,.png'" ngf-pattern="'.jpg,.png'" ngf-max-size="'500KB'">
```

My problem is when I try to check personalImageFile.$error because personalImageFile is always undefined when I select a file that does not meet the validation requirements specified by the various ngf-.

Do I miss something?

Comment: Can you provide some code of your error checking? If you want to check for a required error you need attr.$error.required but you need to specify the name of the input via name="attr"

Comment: Use `ngf-model-invalid="invalidFiles"` and check the $error on those invalid files.

Comment: ngf-model-invalid did the job thanks! I haven't seen it in the docs before, my error sorry.

Comment: Hi danial,can u post piece of code for the same,i am not able to show errors in UI

Comment: I tried the ngf-model-invalid, however, the error seems to be delayed... when i first upload an invalid pattern, invalidFile is null... then on the second upload of the same invalid pattern, then invalidFile has $error=pattern... then on the third upload, i try a invalid size, then the invalidFile has $error=pattern... then on the 4th attempt, i try to upload a valid file, then the invalidFile has $error=maxSize... why is it so?